# JS read in JSON object from local file

Tags: javascript, json, intellij-idea

I have a simple JS form that takes a search term and a drop down option and returns JSON data based on those parameters. I believe the issue I'm running into is that even though intelliJ sees the reference to the other file, it's unable to process it ('Unexpected Token Error).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rf8b5hy/)
JSON Fragment:

```
var songs = [
{"title":"12-Bar Original"                      , "writer":"Lennon, McCartney, Harrison and Starkey     ", "vocalist":"Instrumental                                 "},
{"title":"Across the Universe"                  , "writer":"Lennon                                      ", "vocalist":"Lennon                                       "},
{"title":"Act Naturally"                        , "writer":"Russell, Morrison                           ", "vocalist":"Starkey                                      "},
{"title":"Ain't She Sweet"                      , "writer":"Yellen, Ager                                ", "vocalist":"Lennon                                       "},
{"title":"All I've Got to Do"                   , "writer":"Lennon                                      ", "vocalist":"Lennon                                       "},
{"title":"All My Loving"                        , "writer":"McCartney                                   ", "vocalist":"McCartney                                    "},
{"title":"All Things Must Pass"                 , "writer":"Harrison    —   —                           ", "vocalist":"                                             "},
{"title":"All Together Now"                     , "writer":"McCartney, with Lennon                      ", "vocalist":"McCartney, with Lennon                       "},
{"title":"All You Need Is Love"                 , "writer":"Lennon                                      ", "vocalist":"Lennon                                       "},
{"title":"And I Love Her"                       , "writer":"McCartney, with Lennon                      ", "vocalist":"McCartney                                    "}];
```

Thoughts on this? I'm sure I'm missing something silly. Appreciate the eyes. Thanks!

Comment: This is a JS code, not a JSON. How do you use it? Load via ajax or smth? If so, remove "var songs = " and trailing ";".
If you want the JS code to be run - e.g. add a global var "songs", you can eval the file text. You can also modify the code to be a module and require it via RequireJS for example, or simply load the file in script tag.

Comment: @PavelStaseljun - No, it is perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: Rly? What the string "var songs =" stands for in JSON?

Comment: `var songs =` is a variable reference to the JSON.

Comment: Right. My hope was to use the variable or write a function reference that can be called in the main functions. Just don't want all that data in the main file, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your variable `songs` already holds a valid JSON data and doesn't need to be parsed. `JSON.parse` would be required if your variable held a JSON string. That is why `JSON.parse` throws the unexpected token error. You can simply get rid of the `JSON.parse` and use just `songs`.

Comment: This makes sense to me. The page appears to still not be accessing anything though, and refreshing after momentarily displaying the entered text. Is there something else I might be missing?

Comment: Here's an update to your jsFiddle that works. I had to remove the hardcoded local files you had in your HTML, add the JSON data for `songs` , call the `init()` method as soon as it is initialized, and prevent the default event when the button is clicked. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/5rf8b5hy/8/.

Comment: This looks great, and some helpful tricks as well! I'm still having some issues with her though. And does the JSON need to be in the same file as the processing for this to work?

Comment: The JSON doesn't have to be on the same file, as long as it is accessible (as a global variable, or passed into the function somehow). I was able to get the search result. Tells us what issues you have so we can help.

Comment: Im not sure. I've referenced your edits, which clearly work in fiddle, but do not return the writer/vocalist value for each search term, but I have no action whatsoever in prod right now. 

https://jsfiddle.net/5rf8b5hy/10/

Actually mine displays the search term in fiddle as well, just not in Chrome...hm
Any insight into returning the extra value in each search, or if I need to make an explicit call with the code above?

Comment: That is because you are calling the functions to check equality first, and then updating the content with the user string afterwards, thus over writing the content. Also, your equality check doesn't work, because for `for(var song in songs)` doesn't work the way you expect. Take a look at the changes I made here: https://jsfiddle.net/5rf8b5hy/11/.

Comment: I have no idea what the issue is here. Your jfiddle runs exactly in the way I was looking for, but running that code through intellij to chrome or firefox gets nothing. Like the button either resets the whole page or does nothing at all. I've cleared cache as well. I cant figure out why this only works in fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92181/discussion-between-show-me-the-code-and-dreamerdiver).